# Why is this function not activating "then"? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

This function is not firing the first "then". Can someone tell me why?

The function works but "then" does not trigger.

```
export function changeData(url, type, table, message, params, action) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const request = Server.get(url, { params: { table: table, params: params }});

        return request.then(() =>   {   // <- This then doesn't work
            console.log('I'm not being fired')
            Promise.all([                  
               dispatch({ type: type, payload: params })
              ]).then(() => {
                if (action) {return dispatch(action())} 
              }).catch((error) => 
                console.log(error)
              )   
        )
    } 
}
```

**This is the request being called from the above function:**

```
 _server.get(`/insertSelect`, (req, res) => {  
        let table = req.query.table
        let params = req.query.params
        let select = true
        consoleLog('insert', table, params)
        DefaultSQL.insert(table, params, select).then(response => {           
            res.json(response)
        })
    })
```

This is the way I call changeData:

```
export const updateCliente = params =>
    dbActions.changeData(
        'insertUpdate',
        SAVE_CLIENTE,
        `erp_ClientesEFornecedores`,
        'Cliente salvo com sucesso',
        params
    )
```

And my dispatch is from redux

Comment: How exactly do you call changeData function?

Comment: make sure you add `await` BEFORE you call the changeData

Comment: Is your `dispatch` function from redux?

Comment: _server.get does not seem to return a promise

Comment: I have edited with the way I call changeData
Yes the dispatch is from redux.

Thanks for help guys :)

Comment: The `url` values don't seem to match: `insert` vs `insertSelect`?

Comment: I copied the function with different url but both are the same,

Comment: Are you aware that `dispatch` doesnt return anything? Neither a Promise?

Comment: i'm still catching up to learn this. But in this case even a console.log is not being called, I don't think the dispatch is the problem. (The then that I can't fire is the first one, not the second)